# Mysql: How to configure mysql proxy for an existing master-slave setup

Tags: mysql, configuration, mysql-proxy

I want to configure mysql proxy on my test environment to observe the below.

```
1. Behavior of the proxy
2. How load, CPU usage varies on my test server for read/write distribution.
```

I googled and able to install proxy on my ubuntu linux.

But I didnt see any thing on configuring it in a step by step manner and how to start or stop this.

Shall some one explore on this and this would be of great help for me.

Thanks in advance
Regards,
UDAY

Answer (score 1):

By default if you run the proxy on the same machine as the server it will listen to port 4040 and query a backend server on the msyql default port of 3036. Other port numbers and server locations can be configured from the command line or with a configuration file.

To distribute queries across servers, add monitoring, profiling etc. you need to provide a Lua script to mysql-proxy. See the example / tutorial scripts in /usr/local/share/docs that came with the installation download. There is work to do for a production implementation.

The basics of how the scripting works can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-proxy.html) under [MySQL Proxy Scripting](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-proxy-scripting.html).

Don't be worried about Lua. The syntax is quite readable given the tutorial examples to work from. As and when you need it [lua.org](http://lua.org) has more details of Lua.